# Code in Objective C 2008 Does not compile

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm learning the basics of objective-C by Reading 'Objective C For Dummies'.
I'm using XCode 4.4, and I'm trying to get some simple code to work. This question has been posed online before. *However* - the code doesn't seem to compile with the new version of XCode.

At issue seems to be the line NSLog (@"Here is some amazing text! %i",c); This throws an 'Expected Expression' Error. Per the previous form posting, I have disabled automatic reference checking in preferences and this still fails.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    //declare variables
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    //set the variables
    a = 2;
    b = 3;

    //Perform the computations
    c = a % b;

    //Output the results
    NSLog (@"Here is some amazing text! %c",c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What was the "previous form posting" and does it have a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` at the top, and change the `NSLog` to this:

```
NSLog (@"Here is some amazing text! %d",c);
```

Because `%c` doesn't mean "a variable called `c`", but rather a `char`. `%d` means an `int`, which is what `c` is.

Comment: "NEVER, ever, EVER disable ARC" unless you're working through a book from 2008. Then disable ARC by all means. Also note that you can use bold instead of caps in your answers.

Comment: @Yar: True, but you shouldn't be using a book from 2008 unless you're maintaining legacy code from 2008. I want to encourage good form.

Comment: @Yar: Thanks. I never like to see a score of -1 on my posts if I've fixed them.

Comment: @Yar - The cioyright date on this text is: 'Pub. Date: October 05, 2009' ... I'd love to get something newer if that's more constructive. Can you suggest a title?

Comment: @BradHines what background are you coming from?

Comment: @Yar 3 Years of ColdFusion and ASP.NET forms experience. MVC is a new model for me. I'm expected to learn 'droid and iPhone development for a company I am working for. I know Java reasonably well - I had three classes on it in college and did some projects about 9 years ago in it.

Comment: I like the book objective-c for java developers, just to get a start, but it's pre-ARC, I just realized, so no go there. Take a look on Stackoverflow to see what's recommended.

Comment: I started with the 'Big Nerd Ranch guide to Objective C programming'. It's solid and recommend the title to anyone who reads this thread.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the Foundation header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Sidenote: The format specifier should be `%d`.

Comment: Euh, nope. 1. If it doesn't find a function, GCC assumes it to be int func(...). 2. %i for integers is just fine.

Comment: @H2CO3 Wake up, it's 2012 (and Xcode 4.4), there's no gcc, just clang. Also, there's no implicit function declaration since C99. And %c is surely wrong when sending an int.